# "errorCode": "USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT"

Tags: docusignapi

While Requesting the recipient view in docusign, I am getting the error as

```
 "errorCode": "USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT",
  "message": "The specified User is not a member of the specified Account."
```

Below is the URL that I am referring:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/embedded-signing

I have added the users in specified account and also given the input to fetch the response. But anyhow getting the above error.

```
curl -k -X POST  \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H 'X-DocuSign-Authentication: { 
          "Username":"developer@example.com",
          "Password":"S3cre+p455w0Rd",
          "IntegratorKey":"230546a7-9c55-40ad-8fbf-af205d5494ad"}' \
    -d '{"authenticationMethod":"email",
         "clientUserId":"1000",
         "email":"the_nda_signer@mailinator.com",
         "recipientId":"1",
         "returnUrl":"http://httpbin.org/get",
         "userName":"Darlene Petersen"}' \
    https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/000000/envelopes/4280f274-bfee-419b-9514-b218b7eeda08/views/recipient
```

Comment: Does the user specified in Auth Header - `developer@example.com`, a sender of envelopeId - `4280f274-bfee-419b-9514-b218b7eeda08` in account - `000000` as shown in your recipient view API endpoint?

Comment: This is the example from the docusign itself. I have different input parameters for my app. So the user specified in Auth Header in my request is having the the specified account in main account.

Comment: curl -k -X POST  \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H 'X-DocuSign-Authentication: { 
          "Username":"admin@demo.com",
          "Password":"xxxxx",
          "IntegratorKey":"xxxxxx"}' \
    -d '{"authenticationMethod":"email",
         "clientUserId":"1",
         "email":"abc@gmail.com",
         "recipientId":"1",
         "returnUrl":"https://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
         "userName":"abc"}' \
    https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxxxx/envelopes/9d0c197c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4d42d25bb595/views/recipient

Comment: @AmitKBist , Do i need to change the clientuserId and recipentId . I tried with adding the ids from the account but still the same problem there.

Comment: @kirti Do you have both a demo sandbox account AND a production account with DocuSign?  If so I'd make sure you are not using a production user's credentials for your demo sandbox request as some people sometimes do.  Also the `Username` field accepts either the user's email address or their userId, have you tried using the userId to see if you get the same result?

Comment: @AmitKBist, Yes, I have both the accounts, I am using sandbox credentials and in my sandbox account I have added many users. Now the envelope is created and sent to particular user. In this case, in Auth Header, added sandbox credentials but still its throwing same errors.

Comment: Are you getting any response successfully for API endpoint - `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information` with the same credentials? and verify if you are using same AccountId which is return in the baseUri property of the response?

Answer (score 1):

Docusign does not allow cross-account API calls.

What does that mean?

Typical product integrations try to do integration with docusign by using their own Docusign Account (Pro Enterprise) but they want to allow their customers to send documents for eSign using their own docusign accounts. B2B type integrations. This is where the tricky part is.

1. The integration is done with one account.
2. The documents are sent for eSign for another account user (of the product client) by using integration account id (Point 1).

In such case belows errors are thrown by docusign APIs,

For JWT flow,

```
"errorCode": "USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT",
"message": "The specified User is not a member of the specified Account."
```

For Auth Grant flow,

```
"errorCode": "INVALID_USER",
"message": "The specified User is not a member of the specified Account."
```

Solution?

When the documents are send for eSing using docusign createEnvelope API, use docusign account id of the product client instead of integration account id.

i.e.

1. The integration is done with one account (Product account).
2. The documents are sent for eSign for another account user but the account id is of this users docusign account only.

Answer (score 0):

Users who want to send documents need a DocuSign account.

It sounds like your username/ password changed and still it is pointing to the previous account. To resolve you need to update the integration to point to the new account.

[Here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/status-and-error-codes) you can find the status code

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have created new sandbox accounts and tried with that too still its saying USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I can't find a solution

Comment: @SPnL Are you seeing this error for all DS API Calls, for instance are you getting error when creating envelope using API? or are you getting error when trying to get Recipient View URL?